# Create Random number out of certain list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, random

I know that Haskell provides a function for producing a random number between a certain range.

Is there a way of producing random number from a set of numbers ?

Example: Suppose list of `[1, 6, 9]` exists and I want the random number to be out of this list i.e 1 or 6 or 9.

Comment: more like, _pick_ a random item from a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well there are certainly a lot of ways to accomplish this task.  Perhaps the most straight forward is to 1) get a random number between `0` and `length list - 1` 2) Use that number to index the list (`list !! rand`).

For example, if you are OK with living in the IO monad for your random numbers then you could use `randomRIO`:

```
import System.Random

oneOf :: [a] -> IO (Maybe a)
oneOf [] = return Nothing
oneOf list = do
   rand <- randomRIO (0,length list - 1)
   return (Just $ list !! rand)
```

Comment: Note that an immutable array can be used to improve performance as `!!` is O(n)